# Are functions with images in an open, dense, and connected subset themselves dense in the set of continuous functions?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be compact, $Y$ metrizable, and $C(X,Y)$ the set of continuous functions $f:X\rightarrow Y$ endowed with the topology of uniform convergence.

Suppose $A\subset Y$ is an open, dense, and connected subset. Is $\mathcal{F}=\{f\in C(X,Y): f(X)\subset A\}$ dense in $C(X,Y)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Consider $X=[0,1]$, $Y=\Bbb R^2$ and $A=\Bbb R^2\setminus([0,\infty)\times \{0\})$. Then, any curve with range in $A$ connecting $(1000,1)$ to $(1000,-1)$ must go aaaaaall the way back to the second and fourth quadrant. Therefore you can't approximate uniformly the curve $\gamma(t)=(1000,1-2t)$.